# Using Vue.set() and Vue.use() in .vue files

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How can I use Vue.set() and Vue.use() in .vue files? I'm using the vue-cli to scaffold my project and I need to use Vue.use(VeeValidate) for validation. Also I would like to use something like following, found [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats).

```
Vue.set(example1.items, indexOfItem, newValue)
```

Since the .vue files export object, How do I get the Vue reference. Also I would like to use it inside my default object exported in .vue files. What I mean is that I need to use Vue.set() on an item present in my data function.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to use `import` wherever you need `Vue` or `vee-validate`, you can do it like following inside the script tag:

```
<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate'

Vue.use(VeeValidate)
...
...
</script>
```

If you just want to do `Vue.set`, you can instead do [this.$set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set) which  is the alias of the global [Vue.set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set).

Comment: So I can do `import Vue from 'vue'` and `
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate'` from any child component and use validation there? Or should I only use this in my main.js file?

Comment: @donnyjeremiah You can do it either way, both are equivalent, but if this is being used in multiple components, than do it in `main.js` file.

Answer (score 10):

Your components have `Vue.set` available as `this.$set`. For reference: [instance methods & properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Instance-Properties).

`Vue.use` is a global method and can be called wherever. It is basically never called inside a component(and might actually throw if you try? Never tried it). Call it wherever you're doing the rest of your initialization.

Comment: Is there any alias for Vue.use() like this.$set is for Vue.set(), so I can use it in the component I wish to use validation for? Because I don't want to use Vue.use(VeeValidate) in my main.js file where I initialize App.vue. I want it only for a certain component.

Comment: It is a plugin. It will load and install globally, even if `import`ed and `use()`'d in just one component.

Comment: I agree with @donnyjeremiah i would like to use some modules in protected routes and not globally registering them in main.js problem is i need to import vue in these protected routes as well.